# WP not displaying the latest version upgrade button

Tags: upgrade

I've downloaded the WordPress project from PRODUCTION environment to my LOCAL MACHINE.

I'm not seeing any UPDATE NOW button or links on my LOCAL ENVIRONMENT. Please see the below screenshot

[image]

But the UPDATE NOW links are displaying on PRODUCTION environment.Please see the below screenshot

[image]

What am I missing. What should I need to get this done ?

I'm using XAMPP.

Comment: check `http://locahost/yoursite/readme.html` in your local and compare with corresponding `readme.html` in production.

Comment: @@KArun - Both are same

Comment: You can try using `define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );` in `wp-config.php` file

Comment: @@Karun - Its not working. Any other suggestions plz...

Comment: I don't have the points to vote the answer below, but removing the /wp-content/mu-plugins/ worked for me. Now I can update WP.

Answer (score 1):

Did you migrate from managed wp to unmanaged? Check this page
https://ru.godaddy.com/help/move-a-managed-wordpress-site-to-an-unmanaged-wordpress-account-19798

In the site directory, locate the /wp-content/mu-plugins/ directory, and delete the gd-system-plugin and gd-system-plugin.php files.

In the wp-config.php file, find and remove the reference to gd-config.php. The sample code below from the wp-config.php file shows the general location of the line to delete.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this post with the same problem, I was able to resolve it by removing the `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` directory. This seems to be a leftover Godaddy "helper" which my client previously used to install their website.

Comment: Removing the GoDaddy plugin is one thing, but if the `mu-plugins` directory is present, it could contain code that's required for the site to run.